# Rails 3.2. find by not equal polymorphic association type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a User model with

```
belongs_to :role, polymorphic: true
```

When I query by role_type

```
(rdb:1) User.count
14
(rdb:1) User.where(role_type: 'Student').count
3
(rdb:1) User.where('role_type != ?', 'Student').count
0
```

No matter what I do, I can't match on not equal in this column.  Other columns, I can.

Comment: Try like this `User.where.not(role_type: 'Student').count`

Comment: Scratch that! It is only valid in `Rails 4`

Comment: How many `role_types` are there in the `DB` currently?

Answer (score 0):

My attempt here would be as follows:

1. I would join roles and write a custom sql. Here is a proof of concept:

`User.joins('LEFT JOIN roles where user.role_id = roles.id').where('roles is NOT NULL OR roles.role_type != ?', 'Student').count`

1. I would use a subquery and `EXISTS` postgres function:
   `....where(NOT EXISTS(select *insert proper subquery sql here*))`